# SOAP Magento create product

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I would like to push all information from my database to a magento website.
At the end of [the soap documentation on catalog_product.create](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html), there is an example of how to connect to the soap and how to create the product.

Here is my problem, the first line is not even working:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($host."/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");
```

This is failing and return this error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'xxxxxxxx/api/v2_soap/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity
>   "xxxxxxxxxxx/api/v2_soap/?wsdl"

I also tried other URL that work, but I do not find anything on these methods and don't know how to use them. For example,  `soap/default?wsdl&services=bundleProductLinkManagementV1`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server configuration, you might need to use index.php:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($host."index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");
```

I've double checked this on some of my own Magento installs and the WSDL does appear.

Comment: Yep, i also tried that, but the result was the same. Ty !